# How do you fix "new !(function" that's generated

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, expo, babeljs

I am getting a error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '!'

I tracked it down to this

```
var nativeEventEmitter = new !(function webpackMissingModule() { 
  var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'react-native-web/dist/exports/NativeEventEmitter'");
  e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; 
  throw e; 
}())();
```

And it appears to be because of `new !(function`

I am not exactly sure what it causing it.  But it is after the Expo 46 to 47 upgrade.

Comment: [wp/wp#6191](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6191)

Comment: so basically there's an import require for react-native-web/dist/exports/NativeEventEmitter somewhere